# how to delete a row without refreshing using rowcommand event

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void Gvaddproduct_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.ToUpper() == "DELETE")
    {
        int? DeleteProductStatus;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
        int index = row.RowIndex;
        objhatcheryPL.sno1 = Convert.ToInt16(Gvaddproduct.DataKeys[index].Value);
        DeleteProductStatus = objhatcheryBAL.ProductDetDelete(objhatcheryPL);
          FillProductDetails();

        if (DeleteProductStatus.Equals(1))
        {

            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "UpdateDetails", "alert('Deleted Successful');", true);


        }

    } 


}
```

with this code am not getting directly row deleting.what's wrong in this,can anybody help me

Comment: Exactly what you need?Why you are refreshing?Whats your problem

Comment: @Bhagavan i want to delete a Row.I had written code for that but am not getting output without refreshing.So i want to delete row directly  without refreshing

Comment: @santhosa make sure you are calling grid after your deletion.

Comment: @Bhagavan yah am calling grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think,you are not adding gvaddproduct_RowDeleting() event...please check the code once again

Comment: This is not an answer. Write this as comment.

Comment: @Samba How rowdeleting   event is related to context